# Fréchet differentiability of functional defined by a integral

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control

I want to prove that if the functional $I: \mathcal{C}^1[t_0,t_f] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
I(x) = \int_{t_0}^{t_f} F(x, \dot{x},t)\,dt
$$
is Fréchet differentiable if $F$ is differentiable with respect to all its arguments.
The definition of Fréchet differentiability is 
$$
I(x+h) = I(x)+A(h)+ \epsilon(h)\lVert h \rVert
$$
where $\epsilon(h) \rightarrow 0$ as $\lVert h \rVert \rightarrow 0$. The norm $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is the maximum value in the interval. We call $A(h)= I'(x)h$ the functional derivative.

So far I got that if $F$ is differentiable then for some variation $h \in \mathcal{C}^1[t_0,t_f]$ we have
$$
I(x+h) = \int_{t_0}^{t_f} F(x, \dot{x},t) + \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, \dot{x},t)h+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}(x, \dot{x},t)\dot{h} + \varepsilon(h(t))\lVert h(t) \rVert_2  \,dt
\,dt
$$
where $\varepsilon(h(t)) \rightarrow 0$ as $h(t)\rightarrow 0$.
The first term in the integral is $I(x)$ and the second term we call
$$
A(h) = \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}(x, \dot{x},t)h+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot{x}}(x, \dot{x},t)\dot{h}
$$

So we are left with
$$
I(x+h) = I(x) + A(h) + \int_{t_0}^{t_f} \varepsilon(h(t))\lVert h(t) \rVert_2  \,dt
\,dt
$$

In addition I know that
$$
\int_{t_0}^{t_f} \varepsilon(h(t))\lVert h(t) \rVert_2  \,dt \leq \lVert h \rVert \int_{t_0}^{t_f} \varepsilon(h(t)) \,dt
$$

It looks like a have some pieces of the puzzle but I can't put it together.
I'm doing my thesis on optimal control so I'm trying to avoid advanced math.

Comment: *I'm doing my thesis on optimal control so I'm trying to avoid advanced math.* Sounds like a not-so-good plan...

Comment: @Dirk It rather depends on what is considered "advanced", surely?

Comment: I suspect it would be false since $F$ involves the derivative of $x$ which is in no way controled by the sup norm of $x$.

Comment: It is not even continuous in general, since it involves $\dot x$.

Comment: Not even well-defined, in general

Comment: I forgot to add the $^1$, the functional $I$ is actually  $I:\mathcal{C}^1[t_0,t_f]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

The proof that I'm intending to do arised from seeing some demonstrations for some theorems for variational calculus (e.g.: Euler-Lagrange eq.) in the textbooks where they assume that $F$ is differentiable and apply Fréchet/Gateaux derivatives.